# Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.CrystalActiveXReportViewerLib105, Version=10.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

Could not load file or assembly

```
Interop.CrystalActiveXReportViewerLib105, Version=10.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
```

How to fix it?
I'm very tired about this problem. please help me!!!

when i load application `AxCrystalActiveXReportViewer1` has been error

[image]

Comment: There is no context what so ever in your question. Please provide clear details as to what you have tried so far. It is very difficult to suggest a solution by just looking at the exception.

Comment: what visual studio version are you using?

Comment: Do you have reference of this file on your project?

Comment: AxInterop.CrystalActiveXReportViewerLib105.dll

Comment: Microsoft visual  studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:
1. It requires another dll that is not referenced.
2. Check the .net framework that your app is using and that of the dll(which is used to build it).

Comment: i have dll reference  AxInterop.CrystalActiveXReportViewerLib105.dll

Comment: I hope you have correct version of dll w.r.t your .net framework.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>